# Deployment of webapp in wildfly using Context Descriptors

Tags: wildfly

I searched using "How to set Context Path in Wildfly", but got no success. Can anyone help me on how to do it..?

I've used the following code to set the Context Path in tomcat where I can access my application directly using `localhost:8080/myApp`

`myApp.xml` contains as follows and placed at `$CATALINA_BASE\conf\[enginename]\[hostname]\myApp.xml`

```
<Context path="myApp" docBase="G:\workspace\j2ee\myProject\myWebApp\WebContent" />
```

similar or equivalent type of configuration want to use in `Wildfly` server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your standalone.xml configuration you want to add a deployment like this:

```
<deployments>
    <deployment name="myProject" runtime-name="myProject.war">
        <fs-archive path="G:/workspace/j2ee/myProject/myWebApp/WebContent"/>
    </deployment>
</deployments>
```

Then within WebContent/WEB-INF create a file called jboss-web.xml with a configuration similar to:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/my-context-path</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

If this doesn't work you may need to rename WebContent directory to WebContent.war, even if it is exploded it may want .war in the name.

Comment: How to specify docBase, application is not war

Comment: your docbase in tomcat is effectively a war file. Are you saying you are just pointing to a directory without a WEB-INF directory?  Wildfly doesn't support just filesystem deployments like this.

Comment: My docBase is not war file, pointing to WebContent of project directory which contains WEB-INF directory.

Comment: updated my answer. you may need to toy around with it a little bit.

Comment: Thaks @Terrence Curran